# Client can not connect to the server program in the LAN

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, server, lan

I have this class constructor in C++ :

```
SocketServer::SocketServer(int port)
{
    this->port=port;

WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &WSAData);
server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(port);

bind(server, (SOCKADDR *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
}
```

The client application with port no. 5555 can't connect to the server program on the another pc within the LAN network. I have tried different port no. too. How to resolve this? The error message is :

```
Error while connecting
```

: This is client.cpp :

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "SocketClient.h"

using namespace std;

void onError(errorStruct *e)
{
    cout << e->message << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int port;
    cout<<"Enter a port : ";
    cin>>port;
    SocketClient client("127.0.0.1", port);
    client.setErrorCallback(onError);
   client.connect();

string str;
while(1)
{
    cout << ">";
    getline(cin, str);
    client.send(str);
}

client.close();
}
```

Edit 2 : SocketClient

```
SocketClient::SocketClient(std::string ip, int port)
{
    this->ip=ip;
    this->port=port;
    this->connected=false;
    initParameters();
    initSocket(ip, port);
}

void SocketClient::initSocket(std::string ip, int port)
{
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &WSAData);
    this->socket = WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    this->addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip.c_str());
    this->addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    this->addr.sin_port = htons(port);
}

void SocketClient::initParameters()
{
    this->bytes_for_package_size=16;
    this->size_of_packages=2048;
    this->callback=NULL;
    this->callbackError=NULL;
    this->thread_started=false;
    this->errorWhileReceiving=false;
    this->errorWhileSending=false;
}
```

Comment: I recommend that you move the call to `WSAStartup` from out of the constructor of the class and into `main()`, before you start creating Servers or Clients. That way if you have multiple copies of the same class, you won't re-initialise WinSock every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your system works fine if the Server and Client are both on the same machine?

In your client code you have the line

```
SocketClient client("127.0.0.1", port);
```

You haven't given the code for `SocketClient`, but I guess that this is the address and port of the server? If so, then your problem is that you need to give the IP address of the server: `127.0.0.1` is `localhost`, or *this* computer.

Comment: It is working fine on the same machine. I don't know what to write at 127.0.0.1? I tried the ipv4 address of the pc running server program but it didn't work. I also tried the address of the modem (by which both computers are connected) which is 192.168.1.1 but it is again not working.

Comment: You should use the IP address of the server, not the modem/router. It is the _server_ that is listening on port 5555, not the modem/router. It is probably your firewall on the server not allowing the listen. Check that.

Comment: Question details are edited! How to get the ip address of the server? Sorry I'm new to socket programming.

Comment: Is the server Windows or Linux? Windows: open a `cmd` prompt and type `ipconfig`. Linux: open a shell and type `ifconfig`. Look through all the IP addresses listed for `192.168.1.???`

Comment: It is on windows sir.  IPv4 Address 192.168.1.101  Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.0 Default gateway: 192.168.1.1

Comment: Which one to use sir?

Comment: The IP address! `192.168.1.101`. The others tell the server _about_ the IP address and the gateway, not itself.

Comment: Thank you sir! It worked. Last doubt; If I transfer the client and server program to another place (another LAN network) then the ip address will change! In that case, what should I do? Any function or method?

Comment: Unfortunately that's a whole new aspect of IP called Domain Name Service, or DNS. You need to know the name of the server instead (like `www.google.com`) - but it might have lots of IP addresses. Look up `gethostbyname()`